# Application error: there was a network error(file:///assets/www/index.html

Tags: eclipse, cordova

I am trying to run a phonegap application on eclipse juno.
The android version is 4.1.2. The application gives an error saying:

Application error: there was a network error(file:///assets/www/index.html 
when i try to run the app.

The android manifest is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.initial.belgium" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="belgium" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
</manifest>
```

The java source is as follows:

```
package com.initial.belgium;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class belgium extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///assets/www/index.html"); 
    }
}
```

Could someone help me fix this??
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any files linked in your index.html that require internet access? Like a JS file or CSS file.

Comment: No.. Nothing of that sort.

Comment: Perhaps! Try adding this line super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); just above the super.loadUrl method. See if that works.

Comment: Added,
Its giving the same error.

Comment: super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.htm"); Use this even though the location points you "assets" folder.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///assets/www/index.html");
```

To:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: I did. That was the default url location. But it gave the same error.

Comment: @user2511113 Have you tried moving all your external resources to your assets folder? (example: Jquery javascripts, etc.)

Comment: No none of them.... I thot i'll do that after the initial one works. BUt even the default files are not getting loaded soo... was wondering.

Comment: The error you are commenting usually appears when your app can't access some remote files, because you don't have permision (not your case), network issues, firewalls, delays, etc. That's why I was suggesting to move all your JS to the local folder. Maybe you can try to load a "hello world" index.html without JS to verify that the problem is not coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that the Phonegap "Hello World" tutorial for Android simply does not work. It created a sub-folder under platforms / android / assets called "phonegap-app-hello-world-3.1.0". This folder is where all the files were, so once I changed the loadUrl parameter to reflect that it loaded without the error:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-app-hello-world-3.1.0/www/index.html");
```

Hope this helps someone, would have saved me a couple of hours of mucking around!

Answer (score 1):

I found a really good solution to this online.

What you basically need to do is to move the contents of index.html to another file, say app.html.

Then have the following code in your original index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>tittle</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script>
           window.location='./app.html';
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The connection to the server won't timeout anymore and the app should load successfully.

Now I didn't come up with this great idea. All credit goes to Robert Kehoe:

https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/

Doing this helped me solve a similar problem with my own Android phonegap application...

Answer (score 0):

`.loadUrl` should take a url that is pointing to a server. Change it to `http://www.google.com/` and it should work.

To use your own files, upload them to a web server or start one on your local machine. If you are on a mac, there is one built-in (simply enable Web Sharing from System Setting). Or if you have Python installed, you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from the `/assets/www` directory, and then change the URL to `'http://localhost:8000/index.html'`

Comment: Thank you
I changed that. There is an error in the LogCat:

06-24 05:59:22.662: E/Trace(1582): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: I'm working on windows 7. Does the functioning of this differ from system to system??Because the same piece of code works fine on another system

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by the fact that I edited and renamed both an index.html file and an app.js file. When I renamed I included the extension .html and .js. This caused the files to be renamed to index.html.html and app.js.js. So clearly the project could not find the files it was looking for. I believe this is a manifestation of the answers given above.