# IBM Worklight 6.1 [Application Error] There was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

On android: The app sometimes gives [Application Error] There was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/index.html).

searched in others answers but not worked.

Below is my Appname.js in the path:

android/native/src/common/Appname/Appname.java

```
public class appName extends WLDroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * onWLInitCompleted is called when the Worklight runtime framework initialization is complete
     */
    @Override
    public void onWLInitCompleted(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.loadUrl(getWebMainFilePath());
        // Add custom initialization code after this line
    }

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When does the error show up? Is it affecting your code somehow? Also, are you connecting on startup to the server, or is it at any point when you connect to the server? If so, do you have network access from the device/simulator to your server?

And also, you pasted your Appname.java, and unless you are getting a specific Android error from that file, it is useless, and I think you meant to show the main.js file.

Finally, are you using an app upgraded from pre-6.1, or an app created in 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

What is it both index.html and appname.java/js? 
In Worklight 6.1.0.x, a new application is given index.html and main.js/main.css/appname.java

Did you rename any of your project files?
What is the value for mainFile in application-descriptor.xml? Make sure it is "index.html".

Comment: it is index.html only and the code provided by me is appname.js because the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268760/application-error-there-was-a-network-errorfile-assets-www-index-html doesnt work

Comment: Not helpful. Pleas provide the full Worklight project (export it from Eclipse) so it could be recreated here.